# How to push data from WCF service to console application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I got data as class objects by subscribing the event in WCF. I need to push this data to a console application. Does anyone knows how to do this?

#### Service1.svc.cs

```
public void RetrieveLogData()
{
    ClsMain main = new ClsMain();
    main.OnDataRetrieved += ClsMain_OnDataRetrieved;
    main.ReadData();
}

private static void ClsMain_OnDataRetrieved(Data log)
{
    Console.WriteLine(log.ID + " " + log.Description);
}
```

I got data as class objects  as show in the above code.My goal is to publish this data to a console application.Is anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding. In some cases a console app would call a WCF service and get some data. But what do you mean by 'pushing' data to a console app?

Comment: this question looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739525/how-to-push-data-from-a-subscriber-in-wcf-to-another-console-application